# Xcode variables view gets stuck loading variables when stopped on breakpoint

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm debugging and iOS and the variables view get stuck with a spinning indicator in the center of the variables for up to 5 minutes at a time when stopped on a breakpoint. This happens both when debugging on iPhone 5 and when debugging on Simulator.
Debugger is stuck until this view loads.

I'm using Xcode 4.6.1

This happens on two projects sharing some common code. I tried switching from LLDB to GDB but it did not make any difference.

Comment: Got the same issue using iphone5

Comment: I'm suspecting it might be related to a size of one big c structure i'm using. It's about 5mb but that should be manageable, especially in the simulator.

Comment: I suspect it must be going into a loop. Something like say self.value = value or on those lines.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to hunt this down? I double check for any cyclical references but no luck.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @rraallvv it works for me since XCode 5, still slow sometimes but never stuck for that long.

Comment: I don't see this problem anymore in Xcode 6.1. My problem was way back in Xcode 4.6.  Now everything is ok except for Swift related debugging (that's broken all over the place). Still same project